# how to make template images for pr2_plugs_actions

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Does anyone know how to build PCA-SIFT descriptors in pr2_plugs_actions/outlet_template?
We want to add new outlet template in our building.

Thanks

Chen Cheng

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9929/how-to-make-template-images-for-pr2_plugs_actions/) by [chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/510/chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-05-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, if you want to add a new outlet template, you might want to look at pr2_plugs_actions/outlet_templates/configs for examples of existing templates and generate a new one. I am not sure I understand the PCA-SIFT part of the question. The last time I saw outlet detection, it was using one way descriptors. If you want to replace that with PCA-SIFT, take a look at outlet_template_t class from outlet_pose_estimation package.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Eruhimov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1047/victor-eruhimov/) with karma: 26 on 2011-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1